How to remove the prefix auto added for C# enum when generate tlb
I have a C# dll which are COM visible.
public class Class1
{
    public enum enumTest
    {
        None = 0,
        enumA = 1,
        enumB = 2,
        enumC = 3
    }
}

When use oleview.exe to check the .tlb generated, the enum type will display like below:
enum {
    enumTest_None = 0,
    enumTest_enumA = 1,
    enumTest_enumB = 2,
    enumTest_enumC = 3
} enumTest;

Is there any way to remove the prefix "enumTest_" in each enum memeber? Are these prefix auto added when generate tlb?

http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2010/05/17/interop-remove-prefix-from-c-enums-for-com.aspx
